# Convert scala byte to java byte when using containers

Tags: java, scala, interop

I need to call java api which works with byte sequences

```
public class JBytes {
    public static void single(Byte b) {
    }

    public static void array(byte[] arr) {
    }

    public static void iterable(Iterable<Byte> it) {
    }
}
```

from scala

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

class SBytes {

  val b: Byte = ???

  val arr: Array[Byte] = ???

  val iter: Iterable[Byte] = ???

  JBytes.single(b)

  JBytes.array(arr)

  JBytes.iterable(iter.asJava) // Compiler fails with found: Iterable[scala.Byte] required: Iterable[java.lang.Byte]

  JBytes.iterable(iter.map(_.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Byte]).asJava) // works
}
```

Can I do it without using instanceOf[java.lang.Byte] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `valueOf` method of `java.lang.Byte` class

another is to simply declaring type annotation

```
scala> val a: Byte = 1
a: Byte = 1

scala> val b: java.lang.Byte = a
b: Byte = 1

scala> b.getClass
res6: Class[_ <: Byte] = class java.lang.Byte
```

`b` is now `java.lang.Byte`

## Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

implicit class ByteOps(v: Byte) {
  def toJavaByte: java.lang.Byte = java.lang.Byte.valueOf(v.toString)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class ByteOps

scala> val a: Byte = 1
a: Byte = 1

scala> a.toJavaByte
res4: Byte = 1
```